# Find the first and the last days of an array of special days in a given period of time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

Given a period of time, how can i find the date of the first monday and the last friday in that period of time in JavaScript.

**Example** :

- the period of time : from 28/01/2023 to 21/02/2023.
- given dates :  ['MON', "FRI"].
- expectation : return the date of the first day found from the given dates and the date of the last day found from the given dates.

I would like to make the following :

```js
const startDate = "28/01/2023";
const endDate = "21/02/2023";
const days = ['MON', "FRI"];

const findDate = (startDate , endDate, days) => {
  return date 
}
```

in this example : the function returns 30/01/2023 (monday) and 20/02/2023 (monday).

another example :

- the period of time : 28/01/2023 - 25/02/2023
- returns : 30/01/2023 (monday) and 24/02/2023 (friday)

another example :

- the period of time : 31/01/2023 - 25/02/2023
- returns : 3/02/2023 (friday) and 24/02/2023 (friday)

Thank you

Comment: Re `new Date(d[2] + '/' + d[1] + '/' + d[0])`. It doesn't make sense to parse the string to create another string in an unsupported format that must then be parsed by the built–in parser. `new Date(d[2], d[1] - 1, d[0])` is reliable and more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a functional programming way given your new requirements:

```
const allDays = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"];
const startDate = "31/01/2023";
const endDate = "26/02/2023";

 //  Convert a "dd/MM/yyyy" string into a Date object
 function convertToDate(dateString) {
  let d = dateString.split("/");
  let dat = new Date(d[2] + '/' + d[1] + '/' + d[0]);
  return dat;
}
  
function findDate (arrayDay, startRange, endRange) {
  const dayToJSDay = {
    1: "MON",
    2: "TUE",
    3: "WED",
    4: "THU",
    5: "FRI",
    6: "SAT",
    7: "SUN",
  };
  const s = convertToDate(startRange);
  const e = convertToDate(endRange);
  const nextDay = a => a + 1
  const previousDay = a => a - 1
  return [
      findDateRec(dayToJSDay, arrayDay, s, e, nextDay),
      findDateRec(dayToJSDay, arrayDay, e, s, previousDay)
    ]
};

function findDateRec (days, day, curDate, endDate, op) {
    if(day.some(d => days[curDate.getDay()] === d)) return curDate;
    if(curDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == endDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) return null;
     const nextDay =new Date(curDate);
     nextDay.setDate(op(curDate.getDate()))
    return findDateRec(days,day,nextDay,endDate, op)
    
}

const a = findDate(["MON", "FRI"], startDate, endDate);

console.log('res: ', a); // res:  [ 2023-02-03T00:00:00.000Z, 2023-02-24T00:00:00.000Z ]
```

Comment: Thank you @Echyzen, but if i change the startDate to 31/01/2023 it must return friday 3/2/2023 as it the first day found of the given array ["MON" , "FRI"]. the same thing for the last day found in that period .

Comment: Ok I edit the code to handle the specification it wasn't clear at first

Comment: There is no need for two answers, both should be in the one answer. This answer has the same issues as the other answer. It should also fix the flawed parsing method of the input timestamp. The use of *setHours* modifies both the input dates if they weren't 00hrs to start with, which might surprise the caller. Its use in this case is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most imperative approach:

```
const allDays = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"];
const startDate = "28/01/2023";
const endDate = "26/02/2023";

function convertToDate(dateString) {
    //  Convert a "dd/MM/yyyy" string into a Date object
    let d = dateString.split("/");
    let dat = new Date(d[2] + '/' + d[1] + '/' + d[0]);
    return dat;     
}
  
function findDate (day, startDate, endDate) {
  const dayToJSDay = {
    1: "MON",
    2: "TUE",
    3: "WED",
    4: "THU",
    5: "FRI",
    6: "SAT",
    7: "SUN",
  };
  const d = convertToDate(startDate);
  const e = convertToDate(endDate);
  while (d.getTime() !== e.getTime()) {
    if (dayToJSDay[d.getDay()] === day) {
      return d;
    }

    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return null;
};

const a = findDate("MON", startDate, endDate);

console.log('res: ', a); // will print res:  2023-01-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Thank you @ Echyzen , this solution is so helpful if we want to find the first date in the given special days array. we need to do the same thing to find the date the last day of the special days.

Comment: The *dayToJSDay* conversion fails for Sunday. It might be more efficient to use an array: `['sun', 'mon', ...]` and use *toLowerCase* or *toUpperCase* on the input to avoid trivial errors. You can also get the day name with `date.toLocaleString('en',{weekday:'short'})` and avoid the weekday mapping object.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet answers OP's original question: "Given a period of time, how can I find the date of the first monday and the last friday in that period of time in JavaScript?" without any iteration:

```js
// SUN:0, MON:1,TUE:2 ... SAT:6
const fromTo=[ new Date(2023,0,31), new Date(2023,1,26) ];

const findDate = wd =>
  fromTo.map((d,i)=>(d=new Date(d),d.setDate(d.getDate()+((i?-7:7)-d.getDay()+wd[i])%7),d))

// example:         MON,FRI
console.log(findDate([1,5]).map(d=>d.toLocaleString()))
```

Please note that the weekdays are entered numerically (see comment in the first line of the code). The function will then return an array with starting and end dates having the specified weekdays after the start date and before the end date respectively.

**Update**

As it turns out, OP actually wants something different: *the first and last days out of a list of "special" weekdays within a given time period*. This can be done with the following script:

```js
// SUN:0, MON:1,TUE:2 ... SAT:6
const fromTo=[ new Date(2023,0,31), new Date(2023,1,26) ];

const findDate = wds =>
  fromTo.map((day,i)=>{
   let d=new Date(day),dwd=d.getDay();
   d.setDate(d.getDate()+Math[i?"max":"min"](...wds.map(wd=>((i?-7:7)-dwd+wd)%7)))
   return d;
})

// example:         MON,WED,FRI
console.log(findDate([1,3,5]).map(d=>d.toLocaleString("en-US",
  {weekday:"short", month:"short",day:"numeric",year:"numeric"}))) // Wed, Feb 1, 2023, Fri, Feb 24, 2023
```

Comment: Thank you @Carsten Massmann , given the startDate 31/1/2023 , it must return friday 3/2/2023 as it the first day found from the given special days ["MON", "FRI"]. the same thing in the end of the period , find the date of a day in the special days array.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand it correctly, this is a clean, self documenting approach

```
const startDate = new Date(2023, 1,28 );
const endDate = new Date(2023,2,21);
const days = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'];
const dayInMillis = 86_400_000

const findFirstDayInDateRange = ()=>{

}
const findLastDayInDateRange = ()=>{
    return  recurseDatesForDay(endDate, -dayInMillis, 5)
}

const recurseDatesForDay = (date, dateStepMillis, targetDayIndex)=>{
    if(date.getDay() === targetDayIndex) return date;

    return recurseDatesForDay(new Date(date.getTime() + dateStepMillis), dateStepMillis, targetDayIndex)
}

console.log('....', findLastDayInDateRange())
```

Comment: Adding a day by adding 8.64e7 milliseconds is not a good idea as in places where daylight saving is observed, not all says are 24 hours long.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that given an array of day names, the requirement is for the first of any of the days and last of any of the days within the range inclusive of the start and end dates. So if the days list is Monday, Friday and the first date in the range is say Wednesday, the first Friday should be returned, not the following Monday.

One algorithm is to start on the start date of the range and iterate one day at a time until the day name is found in the array to get the first day, then to iterate from the last day in the range back toward the start to find the ending day.

It's not clear from the OP whether the range is inclusive, the following assumes it is.

```js
// Parse string in day/month/year format
// Doesn't validate date values
function parseDMY(s) {
  let [D, M, Y] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Y, M - 1, D);
}

function findFistLastDayInRange(start, end, dayNames) {
  let getDayName = d => d.toLocaleString('en',{weekday:'short'}).toLowerCase();
  let s = parseDMY(start);
  let e = parseDMY(end);
  let days = dayNames.map(d => d.toLowerCase());
  let result = [];
  
  // Get first date with a name included in dayNames (forward search)
  while (!days.includes(getDayName(s)) && s <= e) {
    s.setDate(s.getDate() + 1);
  }
  result.push(s<=e? s : void 0);

  // Get last date with a name included in dayNames (backward search)
  while (!days.includes(getDayName(e)) && e >= s) {
    e.setDate(e.getDate() - 1);
  }
  result.push(e >= s? e : void 0);

  return result;
}

// Examples - not exhaustive
[{start: '28/01/2023', end: '21/02/2023', days: ['MON', 'FRI']}, // M-M
 {start: '28/01/2023', end: '25/02/2023', days: ['MON', 'FRI']}, // M-F
 {start: '31/01/2023', end: '25/02/2023', days: ['MON', 'FRI']}, // F-F
 {start: '03/01/2023', end: '08/01/2023', days: ['MON', 'FRI']}, // No M
 {start: '03/01/2023', end: '05/01/2023', days: ['MON', 'FRI']}, // No M or F
  {start: '03/01/2023', end: '08/01/2023', days: ['MON', 'tue', 'FRI', 'Sat']}, // T-S

].forEach(({start, end, days}) => console.log(
  findFistLastDayInRange(start, end, days).map(d => d && d.toDateString())
));
```

The function always returns an array of 2 elements. If only one of the days occurs once, it will be the both the first and second date. If none of the days appear in the range, both values are undefined.

Forcing string comparisons to be lower (or upper) case avoids silly errors like `'Tue' != 'TUE'`.

While iterating might seem inefficient, there should never be more than 6 searches for each end of the array. The logic of two searches is simple to implement and maintain, I don't think a more complicated non–iterative solution would be.

To better fit a functional paradigm, The *while* loop can be put into a separate function with a parameter to say whether to search from the start or end, so after the parameter setup it's just (in pseudo code):

```
return [fn(start, end, days, forward), fn(start, end, days, backward)];
```